# using String split() method with non-white space regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to figure out how it works, I tried several different examples and I just don't uderstand the results I'm getting. fot example using it on string such as:

```
String s1 = "Hello there how are you";
String [] sa1 = s1.split("\\s");
```

will return array with 5 elements which are obvious and this makes sense to me. How about this:

```
String s1 = "Hello there how are you";
String [] sa1 = s1.split("\\S");
```

returns array of 17 empty strings... Could someone help me understanding it please?

Comment: you should use `\\S+` to find anything that is separated by white spaces. [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vH9hS9/1) that returns 5 words as per the example.

Comment: yes, I understand quantifiers thanks for that, but my problem was slightly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex pattern `\\S` means *not* whitespace, so every letter is a separator.

You get:

- 5 empty strings for each empty string before each letter of `Hello`
- 1 single-space string `" "` for the space between `Hello` and `there`
- 4 more empty strings for the empty strings in between the letters of `there`
- 1 more single-space string `" "` for the space between `there` and `how`
- 2 more empty strings for the empty strings in between the letters of `how`
- 1 more single-space string `" "` for the space between `how` and `are`
- 2 more empty strings for the empty strings in between the letters of `are`
- 1 more single-space string `" "` for the space between `how` and `are`
- There would be 3 more empty strings for `you`, but [`String`'s `split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) discards trailing empty strings.

Adding them all up you get your 17 elements.  Most of them are empty strings, but 4 of them are not empty and consist of a single space.